# How do I recompile my PHP modules after installing secondary PHP

Tags: php, linux, apache, compiler-warnings, multiple-instances

I'm trying to install a **secondary version of PHP** (on Linux), so I can test this version on our software before upgrading PHP (from version 5.3 to 5.5). I read that I should be able to install it **as FastCGI to use it from Apache** next to the original version. I have done this before when upgrading from 5.1 to 5.3 and it worked then, however, when running php-cgi now, I get a bunch of **error messages about the modules**.

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/guide/cgi-bin5516/modules/gd.so' - /opt/guide/cgi-bin5516/modules/gd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/guide/cgi-bin5516/modules/imap.so' - /opt/guide/cgi-bin5516/modules/imap.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>
> ...and about 15 others

Obivously a new version of PHP means the modules should be **recompiled**, so I referenced a different extension-directory from php.ini and compiled a few of them:

```
phpize
aclocal
./configure
make
```

(and I moved the resulting .so file to this directory. This only resulted in different kind of error messages:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) 'curl.so' in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) 'dom.so' in Unknown on line 0

Now I'm lost. **What am I doing wrong?** Does anyone have a clue

Just in case anyone asks, these were the options I configured PHP with. Yes, it's a big list. It has historically grown and I'm not sure if all options are still needed, or if one of these options is actually my problem now:

```
./configure --build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu --program-prefix= --prefix=/usr/local/php-5.5.16 --enable-fastcgi --exec-prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin --sysconfdir=/etc --datadir=/usr/share --includedir=/usr/include --libdir=/usr/lib64 --libexecdir=/usr/libexec --localstatedir=/var --sharedstatedir=/usr/com --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --cache-file=../config.cache --with-libdir=lib64 --with-config-file-path=/etc --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d --disable-debug --with-pic --disable-rpath --without-pear --with-bz2 --with-curl --with-freetype-dir=/usr --with-png-dir=/usr/lib --enable-gd-native-ttf --without-gdbm --with-gettext --with-gmp --with-iconv --with-jpeg-dir=/usr --with-openssl --with-pspell --with-pcre-regex=/usr --with-zlib --with-layout=GNU --enable-exif --enable-ftp --enable-magic-quotes --enable-sockets --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-sysvmsg --enable-wddx --with-kerberos --with-unixODBC=shared,/usr --enable-shmop --enable-calendar --with-libxml-dir=/usr --without-mysql --without-gd --disable-dba --without-unixODBC --disable-pdo --enable-soap --without-iconv
```

Update: I also tried compiling php with only the prefix option, but I get the same errors.

Comment: .so extensions are like Windows .dll files. You need to download extensions and place them in the extension directory

Comment: So, where do I download precompiled extensions for PHP 5.5?

Comment: Php.net has a nice selection of your missing extension, if not. You can try a Google search for the extensions for the php version you are using "curl.so php5.5"

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I may be looking in the wrong place, or using the wrong google search words, but I can't find downloadable .so files. Could you give me a link to some place where I can download for example curl.so?

Comment: I'd be happy too. Unfortunately, there are some complications with my ISP currently and will be without full browsing capabilities until later tonight & using mobile internet on a.. We'll, less than adequate device is a problem. When the net is fully back up in the area I'd provide some links. Until then keep trying & let me know if you succeed. Scouts honor

Comment: Be prepared for a little spam on this topic. For which I do apologize for. Perhaps have a look over: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=56974

Comment: The solution mentioned there assumes you have a different .so file somewhere else, but I don't have other version elsewhere.